# How can i put an array as variable in shortcode_atts?

Tags: shortcode

I am trying to create a shortcode with an array as input like so

```
function product_gallery_shortcode($atts) {

extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'product_id' => '31',
            'prodvid' => false,
            'youtubeids'=>'',//['lbRqMddP2jo','eFAxx817rC0'],
            'thumbnr' =>2
                ), $atts));
```

I like to loop throught the youtube id's but i don't know how to initialize the youtubeids as an array

so it reads

```
    'youtubeids'=> array('lbRrePOP2jo','eFAxx17rC0'),
```

regards

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you goal is. Could you elaborate? Currently the variable `$youtubeids` holds that array...

Comment: @kaiser, well when i use the shortcode the values i passes into youtubeids didn't work as an array in my shortcode function. So i had to turn the values into an array again, see my answer

Answer (score 4):

Ok found a solution

```
function product_gallery_shortcode($atts) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'product_id' => '31',
            'prodvid' => false,
            'youtubeids'=> '',
            'thumbnr' =>2
                ), $atts));
etc
```

and i had to turn youtubeids into an array again

```
$youtubeidsnew = array();
$youtubeidsnew = explode(',', $youtubeids);
```

Comment: It is not clear how this 'fixes' your problem ( or what your problem actually was ). Could you ellaborate so that this answer may be helpful to other people?

Comment: As you goal is **completely unclear** (what is the expected output?), it's impossible to understand your "solution". I'm holding back from a downvote, but please elaborate your goal better (edit question) and then elaborate _why_ this is a fix.

Answer (score 2):

I found the best solution for this problem. If you want use array for input of shortcode use this:

```
function product_gallery_shortcode($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
                'product_id' => '31',
                'prodvid' => false,
                'youtubeids'=> array(),
                'thumbnr' =>2
                    ), $atts));
    etc 
    $youtubeids = $atts[youtubeids];
    $youtubeids = explode(',', $youtubeids);
```

In your shortcode input you can use the following for each array index:

```
[myshortcode youtubeids="index0,index2,index3"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way I use:

```
[my param="key1=value1&key2=value2"]
```

in shortcode callback, just do:

```
parse_str( str_replace("&amp;", "&", $attrs['param']), $array);
// var_dump( $array );
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just do:

```
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'product_id' => '31',
            'prodvid' => false,
            'youtubeids'=>array('lbRrePOP2jo','eFAxx17rC0'),
            'thumbnr' =>2
        ), $atts));
```

Comment: yes that what i did staticly but the shortcode looks something like this:
`[productgallery product_id="7" prodvid="yes" youtubeids="lbRfgPOP2jo,eFAEfg7rC0" thumbnr="2"]`

Comment: I'm sorry but there simply isn't enough information to answer then. It's not clear what your problem is, or what an answer would be. We'd need code